# How to find Linux kernel version of my EKS Pod Containers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, linux-kernel, amazon-eks

`uname -srm`

THis gives Linux kernel version.

How to find Linux kernel version of all the containers running inside my EKS deployments? CAn we do it using `kubectl` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check with kubectl if your pod support bash:  `kubectl exec --namespace <if not default> <pod> -- uname -srm`